# Factory methods visibility in Spring Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

Let's consider a Spring 5 project using **only Java configuration**.

```
@Configuration
class AppConfig{

  @Bean
  <visibility-modifier> MyComponent first(){
    return new MyComponent();
  }

  // other @Bean annotated methods
}

// multiple configuration classes following similar structure
```

Trying to figure out what is the impact of `<visibility-modifier>` I've found that there could be visibility effects while mixing XML config and Java config ([example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0-m2a/reference/html/bean-visibility.html)).

It is a bit confusing that documentation mostly uses `public` modifier everywhere
(e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)

**What is the difference between using `public` and other visibility modifiers on `@Bean` methods?**
(when only Java configuration is used)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always use public factory methods. Not sure why you would use other ones intentionally.
But to the question, I only remember that when spring has to choose factory method to use, it gives precedence to public methods. Apart from that I have never come across any other difference. Hope that helps.